# QML problem using virtual keyboard inside a dialog

Tags: qt, keyboard, qml

I am working on a Qt project (v5.13.0) for a device that has a touchscreen but no physical keyboard.
Virtual keyboard works fine in application windows, showing whenever a input component is clicked.

My problem is when I want to fill an input component in a dialog (actually a Popup).
The keyboard does show up, but "behind" the dialog, on the main window, so I cannot use it.

I'am sure I am missing something, a component member for exemple, but I can't figure out what it is.

Does someone have an idea about how to make the virtual keyboard accessible in my dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this issue is tracked by https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56918, and was fixed in 5.15.

There are several potential workarounds discussed there if you can't use 5.15 for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll take a look.